# Issue when defining C struct... (AKA frustration)

Tags: c, struct

Hey so I'm simply trying to define a struct. I'm probably being an idiot, but hey, I'm trying.

Doing this:

```
struct Neuron{
    float mu;
    float stim[10];
    float hist[10];
    int ns[10000];
    float st[10000];
    float cup[8][10];

};


struct Neuron nur1;


nur1.mu = -0.7;
```

Getting this:

```
error: unknown type name 'nur1'
```

I do not understand why this is. It's all in the same .c file. Maybe compilation issues? Simply using gcc my_file.c  on mac OS X. <3 <3

Comment: Don't use `gcc my_file.c` if you are a begginer, use `gcc -Wall -Werror my_file.c`.

Comment: `nur1.mu = -0.7;` cannot be performed from the global scope.

Comment: You need to post more code, minimum the `main()` function.

Comment: Ditto all the above. Works fine within an actual function: https://ideone.com/NAUcTc

Comment: If that's your entire code, you need to put everything other than the struct declaration inside of a function (`main()` in this case).

Comment: I don't think posting more code is necessary. The error he addresses is the exact first error gcc on a Mac gives when what he posted is truly the full file contents. (Second error is error: expected identifier or '(', strangely enough.

Comment: You are leaving out something.  Please post the complete, exact code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It'd be really tight if I could declare these at global scope, is there anyway this is possible? If not, why not? (for curiosities sake). I ask because I'm trying to rewrite a python/cython script I have written, and would not like to spend any time restructuring my actual code, as it gets a little hairy.

Comment: C programs need, at minimum, a `main()` function. Period.

Comment: @HX Well, I tried to help you, but apparently my answer was not useful. Whatever. You can use designated initializers and do `struct Neuron nur1 = { .mu = -0.7 };`, but of course, you always need a `main()` function. Just thought I'd leave this here because it's probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Haha, yup I saw your comment, I was just looking for other shortcuts as well, thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

You can't just say `nur1.mu = -0.7` like that.  Try putting it in a function (maybe your `main` function):

```
int main()
{
nur1.mu = -0.7;
}
```

Comment: Another option, since the OP is using GCC, is to use its (non-standard, non-portable) _constructor_ attribute on a function of any name; that function will get called before `main()` to perform whatever initialization it needs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433484/c-static-initialization-vs-attribute-constructor has some details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a main function; otherwise the complier doesn't know where to look for the start of the first function. The struct is declared outside of main() with everything else inside, like this:

```
struct Neuron{
    float mu;
    float stim[10];
    float hist[10];
    int ns[10000];
    float st[10000];
    float cup[8][10];
};

int main()
{

struct Neuron nur1;

    nur1.mu = -0.7;
    printf("%f\n", nur1.mu);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just to initialize the struct properly, you can use an initializer. This is allowed at the file-level (using only a *constant expression*), or for a local variable.

```
struct Neuron nur1 = {
    .mu = -0.7;
};
```

The syntax like `.mu` is called *designated initializer* (C99).

Note this will be performed once during program startup and will also initialize all not explicitly initialized fields to `0` as for any global object (see [**C11 6.7.9p10**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p10)).

Comment: Not "all bits zero", but as if initialized by the expression `0`.  For example pointers become null, and doubles become `0.0`, even if those values are not represented by all-bits-zero